# Жесты перелистывания

Tags: gestures, android

Есть массив с ссылками на изображения.
Есть ImageView.
Можем ли мы как-либо получить обработать жесть перелистывания влево и вправо и далее менять изображение на нужное из массива? Интересует именно реализация жеста перелистывания.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можем, используя метод `onFling`:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    private void onCreate() {
        final ImageView iv  = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);
        iv.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(final View v, final MotionEvent e) {
                gd.onTouchEvent(e);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    private final GestureDetector gd = new GestureDetector(new GestureListener());

    private static final int DISTANCE = 100;
    private static final int VELOCITY = 200;
    private class GestureListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
            if(e1.getX() - e2.getX() > DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > VELOCITY) {
                // Справа налево
                return false;
            }  else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > VELOCITY) {
                // Слева направо
                return false;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Галерея](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gallery.html) не подходит?